# How do I know if this wooden LEGO duck is real?

Tags: part-identification, history, vintage, wooden-toys

[image: Image of duck]

I bought this wooden duck and I am wondering if this is a real LEGO item.

Comment: "if it quacks like a duck, maybe it is a duck"

Comment: I've never seen a LEGO wooden duck with an upturned bill like that, or without the platform base. It could be, but I highly doubt it. That said, an antique toy expert could help ID it

Comment: @CreationEdge The [LEGO Museum](https://www.flickr.com/photos/blue-moose/3933002990/in/album-72157622407019674/) has a few more variants of the wooden duck (left, second shelf down). Some of them don't appear to have a platform but it's clear there was a lot of variations in the design.

Comment: @Ambo Nice. Some very similar

Comment: Note that the pull-along wooden duck was a very popular toy at the time. Without any markings on the toy or any evidence of another nearly identical copy attributed to Lego, why would one think this particular example was a Lego design?

Answer (score 8):

Every Lego wooden duck I have seen, whether in person or on the internet, is sitting on a platform with the wheels attached to the platform. This is the original version:

[image]

Here is a later version:
[image]

Are there any markings on the toy itself that lead you to believe it is a Lego product?

Comment: There is no lego markings